# Force equal height for all siblings

Tags: html, css, grid

I've got a grid based layout with items that all have variable heights. How can I force all items to have to same maximum height as the tallest element? Is this possible with pure CSS or do I have to resort to javascript?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="top">
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu lectus vitae massa rhoncus ullamcorper sed ut elit. Nam id lacus eu dui 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="top">
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu lectus vitae massa rhoncus ullamcorper sed ut elit. Nam id lacus eu dui 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="top">
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu lectus vitae massa rhoncus ullamcorper sed ut elit. Nam id lacus eu dui 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="top">
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu lectus vitae massa rhoncus ullamcorper sed ut elit. Nam id lacus eu dui 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="top">
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu lectus vitae massa rhoncus ullamcorper sed ut elit. Nam id lacus eu dui 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="top">
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu lectus vitae massa rhoncus ullamcorper sed ut elit. Nam id lacus eu dui 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 980px;
}
.col-9 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}
.col-4 {
    float: left;
    border: solid red 1px;
    width: 33.333333%
}
.col-3 {
    height: 50px;
    border: solid green 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
.top {
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
}
```

Not broken: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0ovnhz7/2/)**

This layout lines up as expected, the problem occurs when an item has a larger text than the other items.

Broken: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0ovnhz7/3/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexboxes deal with that easily:

I've added

```
.col-9{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.col-4{
    flex: 1 0 33%;
}
```

to [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/yf52xr1c/).

Answer (score 0):

The text is pushing the parent container; `.bottom` in this case.
You could fix the `.bottom` container with a `max-height` and `overflow-y: hidden` for example.
You could also use the `text-overflow` property to manage text on the `<p>` tag.
There are a few approaches to handle this.

This is a `<p>` tag "truncate" snippet I commonly use.

```
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```